# Django INNER JOIN and WHERE

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Let me introduce you with the structure. Let's say I have 3 models defined as:

```
class User(AbastractUser):
    some fields...
```

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='unknown', verbose_name=_('Gender'))
...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=CASCADE)
    preferences = models.OneToOneField(
        Preferences, related_name='user_profile', null=True, on_delete=CASCADE
    )
```

```
class Preferences(TimestampedModel):
    some fields...
    method = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, default=None, choices=[(x, x) for x in methods]
    )
```

I would like to write this query with django models, what would be the way?

Query:

```
SELECT * from users as u
INNER JOIN users_profile as up ON u.id as up.user_id
INNER JOIN preferences as p ON p.id as up.preference_id
WHERE p.method = 'TEST'
```

Any suggestions, what would be the cleanest way, also most optimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
User.objects.filter(userprofile__preferences__method='TEST')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But my other question would be, what if I also wanted to select something from that preferences table, will that also be here inside filtered data, or only the data from the user table. (hopefully you understand the question)

Comment: @vukojevicf: you can use `.select_related`, so `User.objects.filter(...).select_related('user_profile')`.